# $M$ is a complex manifold $\Leftrightarrow \overline{\partial}^2=0$

Tags: differential-forms, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, almost-complex

One way of stating [Newlander-Niremberg's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold#Integrable_almost_complex_structures) is by saying an almost complex manifold $(M,J)$ is complex $\Leftrightarrow \overline{\partial}^2=0$.

I'm confused by this, because I can't see why wouldn't $\overline{\partial}^2=0$ be always true.

Let a neighbourhood $U\subset M$ with coordinates $x_1,y_1,...,x_n,y_n$. Then a $k$-form $\omega\in\Omega^{\ell,m}$ will be like:
$$\omega=\sum_{|I|+|J|=k}f_{I,J}dz_I\wedge d\overline{z}_J$$

where $dz_j=dx_j+idy_j$ and  $d\overline{z}_j=dx_j-idy_j$. Then we would have:

$$\overline{\partial}\omega=\sum_{j}\frac{\partial f_{I,J}}{\partial \overline{z}_j}d\overline{z}_j\wedge dz_I\wedge d\overline{z}_J$$
$$\overline{\partial}^2\omega=\sum_{k}\sum_{j}\frac{\partial^2 f_{I,J}}{\partial\overline{z}_k\partial \overline{z}_j}d\overline{z}_k\wedge d\overline{z}_j\wedge dz_I\wedge d\overline{z}_J$$

As the $d\overline{z}_j$ and $d\overline{z}_k$ are permuted, we get opposite signs, so everything's canceled out and $\overline{\partial}^2=0$, regardless of $\omega$.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Somewhere, I must have assumed implicitly that $M$ is complex, but I can't see where that happened.

Comment: Who says that the $(1,0)$ forms are spanned by the $dx_j+idy_j$? In general, they're spanned by $1$ forms $\theta^j$ and certainly these $\theta^j$ needn't be locally exact.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I get it now. Correct me if I'm wrong: the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $T_pM\otimes\mathbb{C}$ is decomposed into $(T_{1,0})_p\oplus (T_{0,1})_p$ (eigenspaces of $J_p$ corresponding to $\sqrt{-1}$ and $-\sqrt{-1}$). I've implicitly supposed that, locally, $T_{1,0}=\text{span}_{\mathbb{C}}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\mid j=1,...,n\right\}$, so that $\Omega^{(1,0)}$ would be generated by the $dx_j+idy_j$, but that is not always the case, right?

Comment: Yes, you've supposed precisely the integrable case. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin, what's the formal definition of $\textit{integrable}$?

Comment: That the almost-complex structure "integrates" to give a complex manifold. But the Frobenius-type criterion in terms of the $\theta^j$ I mentioned is precisely that $d\theta^j$ is a linear combination of $\theta^k\wedge\theta^\ell$ and $\theta^k\wedge\bar\theta^\ell$ (for all $j$). Your assumption was that $d\theta^j = 0$, which is obviously a very strong assumption.